# Py2app - error: [Errno 2] i: 'No such file or directory'

Tags: python-2.7, pygame, py2app

So before I faced this error, py2App was trolling about not finding a module named 'pygame' so I imported pygame inside setup.py and then recompiled it. It worked until i faced errno 2 which is about a file called ' `i` ' but there's no file with such name, i have looked in the given directory

Setup.py:

```
from setuptools import setup
import pygame

APP = ['space.py']
DATA_FILES = [('', 'img'),('','mp3')]
OPTIONS = {'iconfile':'rocket-icon.icns','argv_emulation': True}

setup(
    app=APP,
    data_files=DATA_FILES,
    options={'py2app': OPTIONS},
    setup_requires=['py2app'],
)
```

...

```
copying file /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pygame-1.9.1release-py2.7-macosx-10.11-intel.egg/pygame/transform.so -> /Users/wolf/Desktop/python/dist/space.app/Contents/Resources/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/pygame/transform.so
copying file i -> /Users/wolf/Desktop/python/dist/space.app/Contents/Resources/i
error: [Errno 2] i: 'No such file or directory'
```

Q: how do I Solve this problem ?

Comment: And what exactly is your question?

Comment: question updated, refresh

Comment: maybe it meens that in your code you used string `"i"` instead of variable `i` and you created wrong file name and now program tries to read file with wrong name.

Comment: I just read thru my code and didn't find anything similar to what you're saying.